# Flutter type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Duration' problem

Tags: flutter, timer, format, widget, duration

I use simpletimer package, and it has required duration. So when I try to set Duration(minutes: 5, hours: 1) for example, it shows 65 minutes. So I want to show to user 01:05:00 or 1:05:00 like this. How can I do this?

I found somethings like:

```
 format(Duration d) => d.toString().split('.').first.padLeft(8, "0");
```

but it gives

***"string is not subtype of duration."***

So I am stuck. Help.

My simleTimer:

```
     SimpleTimer(
progressTextStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
status: TimerStatus.pause,
duration: format(Duration(hours: 1, minutes: 3))),
```

Comment: You need to pass a `Duration` to `duration` parameter like so - `duration: Duration(hours: 1, minutes: 3)`

Comment: It is not working, because I do not want to only minutes. If I do this, it gives 63:00. I want to see 1:03:00 not 63:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the `progressTextFormatter` argument of the default `SimpleTimer` constructor.
You can look at the source code to have an example of how to do it: [here's the link](https://github.com/smladeoye/flutter-simple-timer/blob/fa281ae97ea1b31274cef1786d75731b2b7bc80e/lib/simple_timer.dart#L273)

A quick example:

```
SimpleTimer(
  progressTextFormatter: (Duration d) => "${duration.inMinutes % 60}:${duration.inMinutes}:${(duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, "0")}",
//...rest of the constructor
```

Comment: its working but actually not :D 3 hours section is okay, but also it gives 63 minutes.

Comment: actually you forgot to set % 60 for the minutes. So it works, yeah.

Comment: Told you it was a quick example ;)